# ReadBeanPHP SQL query doesnt go throught. Does anybody see a mistake? Did everything by manual and it doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my SQL - query with ReadBeanPHP.

```
$idItem = $this->route['alias']; //some $_GET value

$product = \R::findMulti('listings, users',
            'SELECT listings.*, users.* 
            RIGHT JOIN listings.id_user = users.id_user 
            WHERE listings.id = ?  AND listings.status = 0', [$idItem]);
```

Here is a mistake what it prints me out

```
 Code error Exception

Text error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN listings.id_user = users.id_user WHERE listings.id = 4 AND lis' at line 2

Where error /opt/lampp/htdocs/sellbuyschool42/vendor/gabordemooij/redbean/RedBeanPHP/Driver/RPDO.php

Line error 194
```

I did everything as it's written on official web-site of ReadBeanPHP https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/finding
I want to get couple so-call beans, but getting error. Or if anybody know how easy to combine two tables with ReadBeanPHP that would work to. Providing pics of tables as well.[image: table listings][image: table users]

Comment: There's no `FROM` no table to the `JOIN` and no `ON` for the join condition... Start reading [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/) to learn the basic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `join` statement is wrong, there is no `from` and even you have not declare which table you want to do a `right join`. you can try the following.

```
SELECT 
    l.*, 
    u.* 
from listings l
RIGHT JOIN users u
on l.id_user = u.id_user 
WHERE l.id = ?  
AND l.status = 0
```

Comment: and also it actually gets beans, thank you but they are both empty, have you had this issue?? Thankx